# How to integrate UISearchController with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uisearchcontroller

I have a SearchController that conforms to UIViewControllerRepresentable, and I've implemented the required protocol methods. But when I created an instance of the SearchController in a SwiftUI struct, the SearchController doesn't appear on the screen once it's loaded. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could integrate a UISearchController with SwiftUI? Thank you!

**Here's the SearchController Struct that conforms to UIViewControllerRepresentable:**

```
struct SearchController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UISearchController {
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = context.coordinator
        controller.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = placeholder

        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UISearchController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.searchBar.text = text
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

        var controller: SearchController

        init(_ controller: SearchController) {
            self.controller = controller
        }

        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
            controller.text = searchBar.text!
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the code for my SwiftUIView that should display the SearchController:**

```
struct SearchCarsView: View {

    let cars = cardsData

    // MARK: @State Properties

    @State private var searchCarsText: String = ""

    // MARK: Views

    var body: some View {
        SearchController(placeholder: "Name, Model, Year", text: $searchCarsText)
           .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

**Here's an image of the SearchController not appearing on the screen:**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## (EDIT) iOS 15+:

iOS 15 added the new property `.searchable()` (here is [the official guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/adding-a-search-interface-to-your-app) on how to use it). You should use it instead unless you still need to target iOS 14 or below.

## Original:

If anyone is still looking, I made [a package](https://github.com/thislooksfun/SwiftlySearch) to deal with this.

I'm also including the full relevant source code for v1.0.0 here for those who dislike links or just want to copy/paste (I am not keeping this in sync with any updates to the GitHub repo).

Extension:

```swift
// Copyright © 2020 thislooksfun
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
// SOFTWARE.

import SwiftUI
import Combine

public extension View {
    public func navigationBarSearch(_ searchText: Binding<String>) -> some View {
        return overlay(SearchBar(text: searchText).frame(width: 0, height: 0))
    }
}

fileprivate struct SearchBar: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding
    var text: String
    
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SearchBarWrapperController {
        return SearchBarWrapperController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: SearchBarWrapperController, context: Context) {
        controller.searchController = context.coordinator.searchController
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchResultsUpdating {
        @Binding
        var text: String
        let searchController: UISearchController
        
        private var subscription: AnyCancellable?
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            self._text = text
            self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            
            super.init()
            
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
            searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            
            self.searchController.searchBar.text = self.text
            self.subscription = self.text.publisher.sink { _ in
                self.searchController.searchBar.text = self.text
            }
        }
        
        deinit {
            self.subscription?.cancel()
        }
        
        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            self.text = text
        }
    }
    
    class SearchBarWrapperController: UIViewController {
        var searchController: UISearchController? {
            didSet {
                self.parent?.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            }
        }
        
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.parent?.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        }
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.parent?.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
import SwiftlySearch

struct MRE: View {
  let items: [String]

  @State
  var searchText = ""

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(items.filter { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) }) { item in
        Text(item)
      }.navigationBarSearch(self.$searchText)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for making this, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: This is brilliant! I just have a small change to fix the "Modifying state during view update" warning you'll get: just wrap the line "self.text = text" in function updateSearchResults in a async call like this:

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.text = text
            }

Comment: @G.Marc that and several other improvements have been implemented in the github version (https://github.com/thislooksfun/SwiftlySearch).

Comment: The SwiftUI .searchable() does not support UISearchTokens, so the suggestion to switching to it might be misleading without this caveat.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UISearchController` directly once you resolved **a reference to the underlying `UIKit.UINavigationItem` of the actual SwiftUI `View`**. I made a writeup about the entire process with sample project at [SwiftUI Search Bar in the Navigation Bar](http://blog.eppz.eu/creating-a-swiftui-search-bar-in-the-navigation-bar/), but let me give you a quick overview below.

[image]

You can actually resolve the underlying `UIViewController` of any SwiftUI `View` leveraging on the fact that SwiftUI preserves the hierarchy of the view controllers (via `children` and `parent` references). Once you have the `UIViewController`, you can set a `UISearchController` to `navigationItem.searchController`. If you extract the search controller instance to a distinct `ObservableObject`, you can hook up the `updateSearchResults(for:)` delegate method to a `@Published` `String` property, so you can make bindings on the SwiftUI side using `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice example! I'm curious: Can you point me to a place where it's documented that the parent in SwiftUI is always a UIViewController?

Comment: For single views, there is always a [`UIHostingController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller), which inherits from `UIViewController`.

Comment: However, for subviews in a `NavigationView` hierarchy, I don't think there is any documentation like that. However, if you embed a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, then you'll have one view controller for sure. This code will only run if that controller will ever move to a parent view controller (see `didMove(toParent:)` in [`ViewControllerResolver.swift`](https://github.com/Geri-Borbas/iOS.Blog.SwiftUI_Search_Bar_in_Navigation_Bar/blob/master/SwiftUI_Search_Bar_in_Navigation_Bar/SearchBar/ViewControllerResolver.swift#L45)). So if there is no parent, then this code just won't run.

Comment: You may choose a (popular) hybrid approach, if you setup a `UIKit` navigation hierarchy, and push/pop `SwiftUI` views around in `UIHostingController` instances. Then you'll have direct references to view controllers (mention in the article, too).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! To be honest, I didn't read the full article as I came here from GitHub when I searched for a detail of your implementation (and saw that it's your solution). Right, for a productive use it would be imo better to choose a hybrid approach currently. It's difficult to rely on implementation details right now as Apple might move away from the underlying UIKit architecture, so it's likely the best to ensure having access to the NavigationController by going that way. Anyhow, for other projects which are flexible this resolver is great!

Answer (score 2):

Actually visual element in this case is `UISearchBar`, so simplest start point should be as follows

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct SearchView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let controller = UISearchController()
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchView>) -> UISearchBar {
        self.controller.searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchView>) {

    }

    typealias UIViewType = UISearchBar


}

struct TestSearchController: View {
    var body: some View {
        SearchView()
    }
}

struct TestSearchController_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestSearchController()
    }
}
```

everything next can be configured in init and coordinator made as delegate, as usual.

Answer (score 2):

`UISearchController` works when attached to a `List`. It becomes buggy when you use something other like a `ScrollView` or `VStack`. I have reported this in Apple's Feedback app and I hope others will do the same.

Never the less if you like to include a `UISearchController` in your App. I created a Swift Package at Github named [NavigationSearchBar](https://github.com/markvanwijnen/NavigationSearchBar).

#### Code

```swift
// Copyright © 2020 Mark van Wijnen
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
// SOFTWARE.
import SwiftUI

public extension View {
    func navigationSearchBar(text: Binding<String>, scopeSelection: Binding<Int> = Binding.constant(0), options: [NavigationSearchBarOptionKey : Any] = [NavigationSearchBarOptionKey : Any](), actions: [NavigationSearchBarActionKey : NavigationSearchBarActionTask] = [NavigationSearchBarActionKey : NavigationSearchBarActionTask]()) -> some View {
        overlay(NavigationSearchBar<AnyView>(text: text, scopeSelection: scopeSelection, options: options, actions: actions).frame(width: 0, height: 0))
    }

    func navigationSearchBar<SearchResultsContent>(text: Binding<String>, scopeSelection: Binding<Int> = Binding.constant(0), options: [NavigationSearchBarOptionKey : Any] = [NavigationSearchBarOptionKey : Any](), actions: [NavigationSearchBarActionKey : NavigationSearchBarActionTask] = [NavigationSearchBarActionKey : NavigationSearchBarActionTask](), @ViewBuilder searchResultsContent: @escaping () -> SearchResultsContent) -> some View where SearchResultsContent : View {
        overlay(NavigationSearchBar<SearchResultsContent>(text: text, scopeSelection: scopeSelection, options: options, actions: actions, searchResultsContent: searchResultsContent).frame(width: 0, height: 0))
    }
}

public struct NavigationSearchBarOptionKey: Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {
    public static let automaticallyShowsSearchBar = NavigationSearchBarOptionKey("automaticallyShowsSearchBar")
    public static let obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NavigationSearchBarOptionKey("obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation")
    public static let hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NavigationSearchBarOptionKey("hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation")
    public static let hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NavigationSearchBarOptionKey("hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling")
    public static let placeholder = NavigationSearchBarOptionKey("Placeholder")
    public static let showsBookmarkButton = NavigationSearchBarOptionKey("showsBookmarkButton")
    public static let scopeButtonTitles = NavigationSearchBarOptionKey("scopeButtonTitles")
    
    public static func == (lhs: NavigationSearchBarOptionKey, rhs: NavigationSearchBarOptionKey) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
    }
    
    public let rawValue: String
    
    public init(rawValue: String) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
    
    public init(_ rawValue: String) {
        self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
    }
}

public struct NavigationSearchBarActionKey: Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {
    public static let onCancelButtonClicked = NavigationSearchBarActionKey("onCancelButtonClicked")
    public static let onSearchButtonClicked = NavigationSearchBarActionKey("onSearchButtonClicked")
    public static let onBookmarkButtonClicked = NavigationSearchBarActionKey("onBookmarkButtonClicked")

    public static func == (lhs: NavigationSearchBarActionKey, rhs: NavigationSearchBarActionKey) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
    }
    
    public let rawValue: String
    
    public init(rawValue: String) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
    
    public init(_ rawValue: String) {
        self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
    }
}

public typealias NavigationSearchBarActionTask = () -> Void

fileprivate struct NavigationSearchBar<SearchResultsContent>: UIViewControllerRepresentable where SearchResultsContent : View {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = Wrapper
    typealias OptionKey = NavigationSearchBarOptionKey
    typealias ActionKey = NavigationSearchBarActionKey
    typealias ActionTask = NavigationSearchBarActionTask

    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var scopeSelection: Int
    
    let options: [OptionKey : Any]
    let actions: [ActionKey : ActionTask]
    let searchResultsContent: () -> SearchResultsContent?
    
    init(text: Binding<String>, scopeSelection: Binding<Int> = Binding.constant(0), options: [OptionKey : Any] = [OptionKey : Any](), actions: [ActionKey : ActionTask] = [ActionKey : ActionTask](), @ViewBuilder searchResultsContent: @escaping () -> SearchResultsContent? = { nil }) {
        self._text = text
        self._scopeSelection = scopeSelection
        self.options = options
        self.actions = actions
        self.searchResultsContent = searchResultsContent
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(representable: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> Wrapper {
        Wrapper()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ wrapper: Wrapper, context: Context) {
        if wrapper.searchController != context.coordinator.searchController {
            wrapper.searchController = context.coordinator.searchController
        }
        
        if let hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = options[.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling] as? Bool {
            wrapper.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling
        }
        
        if options[.automaticallyShowsSearchBar] as? Bool == nil || options[.automaticallyShowsSearchBar] as! Bool  {
            wrapper.navigationBarSizeToFit()
        }

        if let searchController = wrapper.searchController {
            searchController.automaticallyShowsScopeBar = true
            
            if let obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = options[.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation] as? Bool {
                searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation
            } else {
                searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            }
            
            if let hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = options[.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation] as? Bool {
                searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation
            }

            if let searchResultsContent = searchResultsContent() {
                (searchController.searchResultsController as? UIHostingController<SearchResultsContent>)?.rootView = searchResultsContent
            }
        }
        
        if let searchBar = wrapper.searchController?.searchBar {
            searchBar.text = text
            
            if let placeholder = options[.placeholder] as? String {
                searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
            }
            
            if let showsBookmarkButton = options[.showsBookmarkButton] as? Bool {
                searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = showsBookmarkButton
            }
            
            if let scopeButtonTitles = options[.scopeButtonTitles] as? [String] {
                searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = scopeButtonTitles
            }
            
            searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = scopeSelection
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
        let representable: NavigationSearchBar
        
        let searchController: UISearchController
        
        init(representable: NavigationSearchBar) {
            self.representable = representable
            
            var searchResultsController: UIViewController? = nil
            if let searchResultsContent = representable.searchResultsContent() {
                searchResultsController = UIHostingController<SearchResultsContent>(rootView: searchResultsContent)
            }
            
            self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
            
            super.init()
            
            self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        }
        
        // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating
        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in self?.representable.text = text }
        }
        
        // MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate
        func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            guard let action = self.representable.actions[.onCancelButtonClicked] else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { action() }
        }
        
        func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            guard let action = self.representable.actions[.onSearchButtonClicked] else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { action() }
        }
        
        func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            guard let action = self.representable.actions[.onBookmarkButtonClicked] else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { action() }
        }
        
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in self?.representable.scopeSelection = selectedScope }
        }
    }
    
    class Wrapper: UIViewController {
        var searchController: UISearchController? {
            get {
                self.parent?.navigationItem.searchController
            }
            set {
                self.parent?.navigationItem.searchController = newValue
            }
        }
        
        var hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling: Bool {
            get {
                self.parent?.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling ?? true
            }
            set {
                self.parent?.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = newValue
            }
        }
        
        func navigationBarSizeToFit() {
            self.parent?.navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```swift
import SwiftUI
import NavigationSearchBar

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var scopeSelection: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<5) { index in
                    Text("Sample Text")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
            .navigationSearchBar(text: $text,
                                 scopeSelection: $scopeSelection,
                                 options: [
                                    .automaticallyShowsSearchBar: true,
                                    .obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation: true,
                                    .hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation: true,
                                    .hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling: false,
                                    .placeholder: "Search",
                                    .showsBookmarkButton: true,
                                    .scopeButtonTitles: ["All", "Missed", "Other"]
                                 ],
                                 actions: [
                                    .onCancelButtonClicked: {
                                        print("Cancel")
                                    },
                                    .onSearchButtonClicked: {
                                        print("Search")
                                    },
                                    .onBookmarkButtonClicked: {
                                        print("Present Bookmarks")
                                    }
                                 ], searchResultsContent: {
                                    Text("Search Results for \(text) in \(String(scopeSelection))")
                                 })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried making UISearchController work with NavigationView and UIViewRepresentable to inject the search controller but the result was really buggy. Probably the best way to do it is to use a regular UINavigationController instead of NavigationView and then also use a container UIViewController where you set navigationItem.searchController to your UISearchController.