# SwiftUI + Embed searchbar in navigation bar center position

Tags: search, uinavigationbar, swiftui

I would like to show `UISearchBar` at the center position of the navigation bar in SwiftUI. We all know how to achieve this feature easily in Swift, but it's hard to manage in SwiftUI.

I tried many ways, search a lot on the internet but not found any relevant post regarding this issue.

Please view the reference image:

[image]

Let me know in the comments if it's still not clear.

Comment: SwiftUI navigation bar allows now only leading/trailing items integration. About UISearchBar the following post might be helpful [How to integrate UISearchController with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59244316/12299030)